# IntelliJ Ultimate alignment assignments with this. not being aligned

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

quick question about intelliJ Ultimate alignments.

These alignments work:

```
exsistingSchedule = new ArrayList<>();
while ((datastring = in.readLine()) != null) {
  String data[] = datastring.split(";");
  for (String sp : data) {
    String        regex       = "%split%";
    String[]      timeBlock   = sp.split(regex);
    String        pattern     = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
    LocalDateTime startTime   = LocalDateTime.parse(timeBlock[0], DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern));
    LocalDateTime endTime     = LocalDateTime.parse(timeBlock[1], DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern));
    String        description = timeBlock[2];
    int           type        = Integer.parseInt(timeBlock[7]);
    int           splitFactor = 45;
    exsistingSchedule.add(
            new Timeblock(startTime, endTime, description, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, type,
                          splitFactor));
  }
```

This isn't aligning, and it's driving me nuts.

```
    public Subject(String title, String description, int ectspoints, String classID) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.ectspoints = ectspoints;
    this.classID = classID;
}
```

Group alignments are all ticked. Infact, I've even tried ticking every alignment option but to no avail. I'd love for this to work.
For the love of all that is holy please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [a known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146487), please vote.